# Permission Denied ( publickey) while ssh to ec2

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I created an EC2 instance and was able to ssh into it properly.

THen I stopped the instance

After again starting it I got the following error

```
Aloks-MacBook-Pro:AWS alokmandloi$  ssh -i working_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
3d:f2:79:cc:38:66:83:71:1b:86:6c:7e:36:ad:27:bc.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/alokmandloi/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /Users/alokmandloi/.ssh/known_hosts:11
RSA host key for ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

I looked up over for a solution and found http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/how-to-fix-offending-key-in-sshknown_hosts-file/

Which suggested that i remove the 11th entry in known_hosts. After doing that i get the following error

```
Aloks-MacBook-Pro:AWS alokmandloi$  ssh -v -i working_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com 
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com [184.73.22.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file working_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file working_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 3d:f2:79:cc:38:66:83:71:1b:86:6c:7e:36:ad:27:bc
debug1: Host 'ec2-184-73-22-113.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/alokmandloi/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: working_key.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stopped the instance, did you try to connect to the new ip address, or the old one? Stopping an instance in ec2 will result in the instance getting a new ip address when restarted.